# How to create a migration deleting a table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-drop

I want to delete a table in my rails app but i cannot use rollback, because i created this table a long time ago, and i have a LOT of other tables created since that one.

How is supposed to be named a drop table migration file and is there a way to genrate it with rails generate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create one more migration to drop the table. The class should have the method

```
def self.up
  drop_table :table_name
end
```

Be careful  as you will not be able to rollback to get all the data you will lose while dropping the table.

Comment: But how do i name it? remove_table_name.rb ? drop_table_name.rb? Will rails know how to update schema.rb?  i always used "rails generate" to create the file, is it ok not to use it ? How do i get the timestamp for my new migration?

Comment: @Sylario - the migration's name doesn't have anything to do with its function. If you write the code properly it'll work regardless.

Comment: You can name your migration whatever you want (should follow the rules for naming of class) .

Comment: @sscirrus: But you do want timestamp in the migration's file name so the file name matters even if the class name doesn't.

Comment: @Sylario just do rails generate migration <migration_name_whatever_you_want> . It will generate migration with timestamp .

Then write self.up and self.down methods accordingly .I hope this will help you.

Comment: @muIsTooShort - you're right that the timestamp is important. My understanding is that `rails g migration ...` adds your timestamp anyway, no? My point was with regard to functionality, but clearly a sensible naming convention is always a good thing.

Comment: @sscirrus: I'm not disagreeing with out, just trying to clarify a bit.